# How to avoid "Sign-in again" when using a VPN with different servers (PIA manager) in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, google-accounts

I'm using Google Chrome stable version 64 up-to-date.

I'm on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit, but I also use Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and Android 7.0.

I connect to the Private Internet Access using their application to different servers.

It often happens, well so often, that it's annoying, that I need to sign into Chrome browser again.

That may be a good security measure from Google's side, but I would really like to know if there is any work-around on this issue?

**EDIT1:**

I mean direct sign into Chrome browser with my google account:

[image]

There appears a red synchronization icon next to my name when I connect to the VPN to be extra specific.

Comment: "Any time you sign in to your Google Account, you'll stay signed in unless you specifically sign out."

Comment: I haven't done anything special and when I start Chrome I am automatically logged in.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Doesnt it compromise security

Comment: Since you are accessing from a VPN and possibly logging in from different locations , I think that Google's intrusion detection mechanisms are getting triggered and they are asking whether it really is you. Can you check this out https://myaccount.google.com/security?nlr=1

Comment: @silberbaum Thanks, but I am unsure what to look for in those myriads of settings there.

Comment: @Vlastimil Look at recent security events and allow the locations if they are being blocked